# Array of objects in js: remove duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with a number of objects:

```
[{"firstName":"an","lastName":"something","linkedInID":"..."},{"firstName":"stefanie","lastName":"doe","linkedInID":"..."},{"firstName":"john","lastName":"something","linkedInID":null},{"firstName":"timmy","lastName":"test","linkedInID":null},{"firstName":"john","lastName":"something","linkedInID":null}, ... ]
```

It's possible that there are duplicates, and I wish to remove them.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2219024/955823) answer got my to the point were I can remove duplicates based on the last name:

```
var arr = {};

for ( var i=0, len=attendees_in_one_array.length; i < len; i++ )
    arr[attendees_in_one_array[i]['lastName']] = attendees_in_one_array[i];

attendees_in_one_array = new Array();
for ( var key in arr )
    attendees_in_one_array.push(arr[key]);
```

I only want a person to be removed when firstName, lastName and linkedInID is the exact same.

I've tried changing `arr[attendees_in_one_array[i]['lastName']] = attendees_in_one_array[i];` to `arr[attendees_in_one_array[i]['lastName'] && attendees_in_one_array[i]['firstName'] && attendees_in_one_array[i]['linkedInID']] = attendees_in_one_array[i];` but that didn't work.

Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: Aren't the `linedInID`s unique? I would think they would be. If so, why not just use those? If not, your accepted answer can remove items that shouldn't be removed.

Comment: Not every user had a LinkedIn ID, so I can't remove on duplicate LinkedIn IDs. You say the accepted answer can remove items that should't be removed. Could you please give an example in which case that is?

Comment: Take two users that do not have a LinkedInID. Let's say the first user is `firstName: "foo", lastName: "bar"` and the second user is `firstName: "fo", lastName: "obar"`. The `firstName + lastName` in both cases will be `foobar`, so the second one will be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can form the unique key from the combination of the 3 values

```
firstName + lastName + linkedInID
```

Like this :

```
var arr = [{"firstName":"an","lastName":"something","linkedInID":"..."},{"firstName":"stefanie","lastName":"doe","linkedInID":"..."},{"firstName":"john","lastName":"something","linkedInID":null},{"firstName":"timmy","lastName":"test","linkedInID":null},{"firstName":"john","lastName":"something","linkedInID":null} ]

var ulist = {}, uarr =[];
arr.forEach(function(k) { ulist[k.firstName + k.lastName + k.linkedInID] = k; });
for(var i in ulist) uarr.push(ulist[i]);

// uarr contains your desired result
```